# How to get the ip address of a particular adapter in windows xp through command

Tags: networking

I have more than one adapter in my system and I want to know the IP of particular adapter. Is it possible through a command in Windows, in Linux it's easy? Or any other way?

Comment: Invoking `ipconfig` doesn't seem much like programming (at least to me).

Answer (score 36):

The following will let you specify an adapter (something ipconfig doesn't appear to do):

```
netsh interface ip show config name="Local Area Connection"
```

You can add `| findstr "IP Address"` to the end of that command to only show the IP address line.

Comment: Hey Trevor, I tried with "netsh interface ip show address" it gave me the actual current ip of my system but when i tried "netsh interface ip show address name="Local Area Connection" " it gave me some different ip which i used in past. One more thing what name i have to provide for getting the ip of PPP adapter can anyone suggest.

Comment: however it would show the ip address only if set as static, it does not show dhcp assigned IP.

Comment: And if you want to find out a name, you can use `netsh interface show interface`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I was able to get my IP Address for a specific network adapter:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %i  in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Ethernet" ^| findstr "IP Address"') do echo Your IP Address is: %i
```

For an explanation of how this works, see my related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004409/2684661

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell

```
Get-NetIpInterface
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
56      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv6                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
17      vEthernet (Default Switch)      IPv6                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
7       Local Area Connection* 2        IPv6                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
21      Ethernet 2                      IPv6                  1348              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
26      Local Area Connection* 1        IPv6                  1500              25 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
25      Ethernet                        IPv6                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
12      Wi-Fi                           IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
56      vEthernet (WSL)                 IPv4                  1500              15 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
17      vEthernet (Default Switch)      IPv4                  1500              15 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
7       Local Area Connection* 2        IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
21      Ethernet 2                      IPv4                  1348               1 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
26      Local Area Connection* 1        IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
25      Ethernet                        IPv4                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
12      Wi-Fi                           IPv4                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Identify your interface and note the ifIndex and then run

```
Get-NetIpAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex  21|findstr IPAddress
IPAddress         : 172.55.23.43
```

To get the IPv4 address.

Answer (score -2):

ipconfig /all should do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to get a particular adapter and this will just list all of them out.