# Batch file help needed - functions, variables and substrings

Tags: variables, batch-file, ip, substring, ipconfig

I'm trying to write a batch script for windows XP. It needs to build an IP address from ipconfig by getting the (192.168.**XXX**.30) XXX part of the address and supplanting it into a template. Then some fun stuff from a network shared folder.

```
SET _var=ipconfig |FIND "192.168"
SET _var=%_var:~25,-4%

net use z: \\192.168.%_var%.30\test_folder

... Do stuff

net use z: \DELETE

ECHO "Tasks completed"
PAUSE
```

At the moment I can't seem to get the result from ipconfig in to my variable, would be even better if I could get the substring from it in 1 line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the lack of a space between FIND and the string a formatting issue?

Comment: just a typo that one, but yeh it would be

Comment: Here's a question that addresses how to put the IP address into a variable:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable

Answer (score 0):

The first task, per your question, is to get the IP address. To get one from www.google.com:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %f in ('ping -4 -n 1 www.google.com ^|find /i "pinging"') do echo IP=%f
```

Say the resulting value of IP is now 192.168.10.20. You can get the third octet of %IP% from a second `FOR` statement:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %f in ("%IP%") do echo ip3=%f
```

The result from the above statement, given the value of the example, would be:

```
ip3=10
```