# Batch File - Get IP address

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with my Batch file.
In my file, i want to get the IP address of my machine as a variable.

Im running Windows Server 2003 R2

So, this is what i tried :

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IP"') do set ip==%%b
set ipAddress=%ip:~1%
echo IP Address : %ipAddress%
```

This work well on my others machines but not on this one because i have multiple ip address in ipconfig.

When i write "ipconfig", this is what i got :

```
Ethernet adapter Local Are Connection 4:
IP Address .... : 10.98.xx.xx

...

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3 :
IP Address .... : 172.22.xx.xx
```

What i want to do is to have 10.98.xx.xx ip in my variable but with my command what i got is 172.22.xx.xx

Thank you in advance and excuse my bad english !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do set a variable in Windows command line to an IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575119/how-do-i-do-set-a-variable-in-windows-command-line-to-an-ip)

Comment: [How do I do set a variable in Windows command line to an IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7575119/995714), [Store IP address in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16815879/995714) [How do I get the IP address into a batch-file variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5898763/995714), another solution is [wmic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27160042/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you've over-censored and retyped the `ipconfig` output.

I'd suggest

```
('ipconfig^|find "IP"^|find ": 10."')
```

to select that entry that contains `: 10.`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip==%%b
set ipAddress=%ip:~1%
echo IP Address : %ipAddress%
```

Comment: could you please also write some prosa text that explains why?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple batch file works. I made this for our EU to be able to tell me their IP.

cd /

ipconfig | find /i "IPv4"

Pause