# Checking for <cr> in if statement in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, windows-xp, cmd, carriage-return

As per [my corrected answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642856/1126551) it seems that Windows XP doesn't strip `<cr>`'s from `for /f` output.

How can I test for the existance of `<cr>`'s in the output?

What I currently have is:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* %%a in ('ping -n 1 example.com') do (
   if not "x%%a"=="¶" ( echo %%a ) else ( echo.>null )
)
```

but no matter what I do:

2) delims= ¶

3) if not "x%%a"==""

4) if not "x%%a"=="
"

5) if not "x%%a"==" "

... I cannot seem to get the if to match the  in the var with any combination of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `FOR` statement, there really is no way that I know of to consistently check for empty lines.

The `FOR` statement actually skips blank  lines, which is what a carriage-return only is, just a blank line.

If it is able to check, you just need to check for an empty string.  Like `if "%%x"=="" echo Yes!`

But try this at the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %x in ('for /?') do @echo %x
```

Then compare it to the output of:

```
for /?
```

And you will see that (usually*) `FOR` does not include empty lines.

*I **have** seen it happen on occasion (usually when it's a pain), but I've never been able to reproduce it consistently.

**Edited Answer**

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that the FOR statement skips blank lines, on Win XP. See the "[my corrected answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14642856/1126551)" in the question for more.