# Printing empty lines and lines that end in a zero to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I have this batch file I am developing. It is supposed to change two values in a config file, let's say ValueA and ValueB. The config file is in this format:

```
[Section]
ValueX=5
ValueA=6
ValueY=True

[Section2]
ValueB=9
ValueZ=4
```

I loop through the original file and write an updated one to `%temp%`.

```
for /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%F in ("C:\config.txt") do call :doline "%%F"

goto :eof

:doline
    set line=%~1
    if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueA=" (
        echo.Width=%valuea%>> %temp%\tempcfg
    ) else (
        if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueB=" (
            echo.Height=%valueb%>> %temp%\tempcfg
        ) else (
            echo.%line%>> %temp%\tempcfg
        )
    )
```

This has two flaws, mainly at the line `echo.%line%>> %temp%\tempcfg`.

1. Empty lines are not printed.
2. Lines ending with `=0` are printed to standard output, not the file. I tried changing the line.

   - `echo.%line% >> %temp%\tempcfg` prints a space in the end of each line.
   - `echo.%line% 1>> %temp%\tempcfg` does the same as above.
   - `echo.%line%1>> %temp%\tempcfg` prints an 1 in the end of each line.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix these?

Comment: Presumably, rather than `%valuea%`, you meant `!line:~7,!` and same with `%valueb%`? Otherwise, these env vars do not have a value. This should work, assuming you are using `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top of the file.

Comment: @wardies Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant there. My code is working except that printing some lines doesn't-

Comment: rearrange `echo.%line%>> %temp%\tempcfg`: `>>"%temp%\tempcfg" echo.%line%`

Comment: @Pietu1998 I mean that the code you provided seems incomplete because the `valuea` and `valueb` environment variables used on lines 8 and 11 are never set. Either my solution below or Stephan's comment above should work but with more work required for the empty lines. Sorry for the typo above: `!line:~7,!` should read `!line:~7!`

Comment: @wardies Yes, I excluded them for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the empty lines are not sent to output? Because they are not processed by the `for` command. By dessign, empty lines are skipped. We need to ensure the line is processed adding content to it. Usual way is using `findstr` to number lines and then removing them

```
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%F in ('findstr /n "^" "C:\config.txt"'
) do call :doline "%%G"
```

`for` executes `findstr` to number the lines, then each line is splitted using the colon as delimiter, `%%F` gets the line number and `%%G` the rest of the line.

Now, inside your `:doline` subroutine, you have to deal with  the problem of the numeric ended lines. This can be solved changing the way to write the commands. Fisrt indicate where to send the data and then echo the data

```
:doline
    set "line=%~1"
    if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueA=" (
        >> %temp%\tempcfg echo(Width=!line:~7!
    ) else if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueB=" (
        >> %temp%\tempcfg echo(Height=!line:~7!
    ) else (
        >> %temp%\tempcfg echo(!line!
    )
```

Or, still better, don't redirect inside your subroutine and redirect the full output of your `for` command

```
@echo off
    setlocal 
    (
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%F in (
            'findstr /n "^" "C:\config.txt"'
        ) do call :doline "%%G" 
    ) > %temp%\tempcfg

    endlocal
    goto :EOF

:doline
    set "line=%~1"
    if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueA=" (
        echo(Width=!line:~7!
    ) else if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueB=" (
        echo(Height=!line:~7!
    ) else (
        echo(!line!
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `%line%` contents are evaluated before the line is parsed. So anything that contains a numeric followed by `>>` is understood to mean: *redirect output to the specified numeric output handle, rather than the default output*.

See: [Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

To solve this, use delayed variable expansion instead; this way, the meaning of the line is parsed before the variable is actually expanded in-place.

The following works for me on the Windows 7 command line.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%F in ("C:\config.txt") do call :doline "%%F"
endlocal

goto :eof

:doline
    set line=%~1
    if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueA=" (
        echo.Width=!line:~7!>> %temp%\tempcfg
    ) else (
        if "%line:~0,7%" equ "ValueB=" (
            echo.Height=!line:~7!>> %temp%\tempcfg
        ) else (
            echo.!line!>> %temp%\tempcfg
        )
    )
```

**Edit:** regarding empty lines, apparently it is expected behaviour for the `FOR` command to gobble these up. See [DOS batch FOR loop with FIND.exe is stripping out blank lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811992/dos-batch-for-loop-with-find-exe-is-stripping-out-blank-lines) for a potential solution.