# IP Address in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, ip-address, command-prompt

I need to figure out how to solely display the IP Address of a computer for my batch file. I don't want the one where it displays `IP Address ................."%IP Address%`

I need it to say something similar to this.

```
set time=&time/t
set computername=%computername%
set IP=%IP Address%
echo.
echo.
echo.
%time% %computername% %IP Address%
```

so if my time was `9:13PM` my computername is `tracckkk1` and my IP Address was `14.14.14.14` then it would say

`9:13PM tracckkk1 14.14.14.14`

and not

`21:13:51 tracckkk1 IP Address.. ...............14.14.14.14`

thanks to anyone that is answering this question!

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, I would just like to clarify one thing. When you said, *‘I don't want the one where it displays `IP Address ................."%IP Address%’`*, did you mean that you don't want the IP address to be formatted like that or that you want a different IP address (not from that line)? Also, is the line supposed to come from `ipconfig`?

Comment: i dont want the ip address to display that line i want it to only show my ip address so i believe that the answer to your question would be i want it to be formatted differently

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the IP address into a batch-file variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following will work

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set /p hostname=Enter hostname: 
    for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping -4 %hostname% ^| find "Pinging"') do (
    set ip=%%a
    set ip=!ip:[=!
    set ip=!ip:]=!
    echo %date% %computername% !ip! 
    )
```

Comment: i would uprate you but im not at lvl 15 yet. Sorry ill do it once i do though

Answer (score 0):

The following will capture the IP address of the computer in an environment variable named `IP_ADDRESS`.

(**Note:** the value of `IP_ADDRESS` will have a leading space.)

```
for /f "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i in (`ipconfig ^| findstr Address`) do (
set IP_ADDRESS=%%i
)
```

Here is documentation for the [`For` keyword](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true).

**Update:** There may be problems with this approach. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20570227/1497596).