# CMD command for getting the IPv4 address alone in Windows

Tags: windows, unix, networking, cmd, ip

"ipconfig" returns all details. but i just want the ipv4.

I have tried "ipconfig | find /I "ipv4" | clip" as well but it returns "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.X.X"

I donot want "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : " as well.

I want the output "xxx.xxx.x.x" nothing else

Is there any cmd command for that for **Windows**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %a in ('ping -n 1 -4 "%computername%"') do @echo %a
```

`for /f` is used to execute some code (the code after the `do` clause) for each of the lines obtained from: a file on disk or the output of a command or a direct included string.

In this case, the second option is used. A `for /f` will be used to run a `ping` command against the computer name and process its output. Inside the output of this `ping` command there will be a line saying something like `Pinging [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] with ....` . This is the line we want process with the `for` command. Usually some kind of `find` command is needed to discard the rest of the lines and keep only the neede one, but in this case it will be not needed.

The `delims` clause indicates `[]` will be used as delimiters to split the line. We want the second part of the line, so `tokens=2` is used.

As the `for /f` processes the output of the `ping` command, each line is parsed. The only line that includes `[]` is the one we are insterested, so, it is the only line that will be splitted, and the only one that returns a second token (the rest of the lines will only output one token as they are not splitted). This token will be stored in the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a` and then echoed to console.

Comment: Thanks alot...!!! Worked perfectly...!!!
could you please breif the functioning of this snippet?

Comment: @Arun, answer updated. Explaining how it works needs much more words than making it work.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer printed out the wrong IP for my situation. I wanted the IP for a specific network adapter and just the IP so I could pass it into a variable and use it.

I used something similar to the accepted answer to achieve this but with the netsh command and findstr in a for loop:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %i  in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Ethernet" ^| findstr "IP Address"') do echo Your IP Address is: %i
```

I explain how it works in this related article:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004409/2684661

I hope this helps some people get what they need.