# Save a specific field from output into a variable on windows CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, netsh

I want to read the wlan-key from `netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security` and save it in a variable so i can display it without the unneeded information like..:

```
echo your key is %wlan_key%
```

I already googled the problem on my own and found a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable). I used the approach from [James A Mohler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007404) and tried to adapt it to my problem but it doesn't worked.
failed attempt:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security^|find "  Benutzer"') do set key=%%b
set key=%key:~1%
echo %key%
pause
```

Comment: Would `for /f "tokens=4*" %%a in ('netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting^=security') do set "key=%%b"` work for your evil purposes?  It's probably not locale-agnostic, but should work if you're reasonably certain your users will all be running English Windows.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, but your solution didn't worked for me. I post my solution in the edit.

Comment: please don't post a solution into the question. Add an answer instead (and accept it)

Comment: ohh..sorry, i am new in this community. I'll change it!

Comment: Please include your (failed) attempty in your question!

Comment: i added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just forgot a simple circumflex between `setting=security`. For my solution i just adapted the above mentioned code.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting^=security^|find "  Benutzer"') do set key=%%b
set key=%key:~1%
echo %key%
pause
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  We call the `^` character a caret.  You're right that a circumflex is probably more accurate in typography and linguistics, since a circumflex is superscript (above the line) whereas a caret is subscript (below the line). However, programmers / scripters are too lazy to type circumflex.  Caret is easier to spell.  Anyway, +1.

Comment: thanks for the plus and the additional info. so far i just knew it as circumflex, but from now on i'll call it caret. It's really easier to write and speak.