# How to get and store the localhost ip address into a variable (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, macos, windows-10, ip-address

In MacOs I used the below command to get the machine local ip address

```
echo $(/usr/sbin/ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

I can also set this IP address into a variable like this as well

```
export DISPLAY=$(/usr/sbin/ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

Similarly like the above how can I get and set the ip address of Windows 10. If I execute ipconfig it prints many things but I need only the local ip address

Comment: Do you have access to the windows desktop? This task is usually done via GUI (I honestly have no idea if the IP can be set via command in Windows). As for system variables, there also is a GUI for it, for local and global variables. Or you just want to do/try this via command?

Comment: @JettoMartínez I want to access this programmetically

Comment: Then, please see if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004935/10621296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find your IP address on Windows 10, using the command prompt, you can use the following command, `ipconfig/all` and press Enter. Your IP Address will display along with other LAN details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but again it prints all the details ....I dont want that....I just need to get only the ipaddress

Comment: I think this has been covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004409/2684661