# Generate certificate for OPC client

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate, opc, opc-ua

i'm coding an OPC UA Client to connect to Sofnet (OPC Server from Siemens). The Server method to connect is SignAndEncrypt so i need a x509 certificate in "der" format.

I made my own self signed certificate with openssl but there is a field called "Subject Alt Names" in which i have to specify the URI's Application. I have seen that this field could be filled with a configuration file with openssl but when i create the cert i can't see the "Subject Alt Names".

Could someone help me to create the certificate or give me a clue to autenticate my OPC Client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a toolkit or SDK to develop your client? These usually have documentation or code that helps with generating a certificate...

Answer (score 8):

You can make a bash file (ie: mkcert.sh) that will do all the process of :

- Creating a 2048bits RSA key.
- Create a Certificate Request.
- Sign it your own key (self-signed certificate) and add the extra information from the extensions.cnf to the certificate
- Get the PEM and DER version of your certificate (opt)

The bash file shall contain

```
openssl genrsa -out default_pk.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key default_pk.pem -out cert.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NY/O=Organization/OU=OrganizationUnit/CN={YOUR_IP}"
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -extfile extensions.cnf -in cert.csr -signkey default_pk.pem -out public.pem
openssl x509 -in public.pem -inform PEM -out public.der -outform DER
```

Then you need the extensions.cnf file that contains the SubjectAltName info and some other information.

```
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
keyUsage=dataEncipherment,keyEncipherment,nonRepudiation,digitalSignature,keyCertSign,cRLSign
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName=URI:URN:{YOUR_IP}
```

Replace in both case {YOUR_IP} with your real OPC UA Client IP.

Comment: How can we make {YOUR_IP} dynamic here ?

Comment: @KishanKishore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable