# How can I extract the IP (Wifi adapter only) of a PC and set it as a variable through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I currently have this simple line in order to write the IP in the console

```
for /f "tokens=14 skip=34 delims= " %%a in ('ipconfig') do (echo %%a)
```

Yet, when I try to input this info into a file, it'll just display the last character shown in the command, which is ":", but I need to extract solely the first line into a text file `%temp%\Test.txt` so I later save it into a variable through

```
set /p IP=< %temp%\Test.txt
```

Tried with Type, but didn't work, I'm currently codeblocked, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the IP address into a batch-file variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not mine, but a blogger called `Fabio Iotti`. Kudos to him.

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do set NetworkIP=%%a
echo Your IPv4 is: %NetworkIP%
```

What I liked for that solution, besides being it a clever way to get it, is that it will output a clean IP variable, so you will not have to worry about snip the string.

Let's take a look at it.

When `ping` is run, it will show the IP between brackets.
Pinging your own computer with `%ComputerName%` will force the command to show your own IP.

Finally, the wide options that `findstr` allows with the use of wildcards allow us to gather the information between the brackets (Remember the `[')` ?), resulting in a clean variable that will only show your IP.

However, I am not sure how this will work if you are connected via WiFi / LAN / USB / Cellular or any other internet capability; how does Windows handle the IPv4 with several connections methods? I am sure that it will be not a problem, but I would like to check it out.